# How to change font size using custom directive in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I want to change the font size of the element using a custom directive

Thus I  have tried below code for that

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello"><label v-onhover>CLICK ME TO CHANGE FONT</label></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CustomDirective",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  directives: {
    onhover: {
      bind(el, binding) {
        el.onmouseover = function() {
          el.fontSize = "100px";
        };
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped></style>
```

Inside the bind, I'm getting the complete label element but don't know how to get it worked  for changing the user-defined font size on mouse hover

Comment: Are you doing this purely as an exercise in writing directives?

Answer (score 2):

You want [`el.style.fontSize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Setting_styles) instead of `el.fontSize`.

```js
Vue.directive('onhover', {
  bind(el, binding) {
    el.onmouseover = function() {
      el.style.fontSize = "100px";
    };
  }
});

new Vue().$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="hello">
    <label v-onhover>Hover on me to change font</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

After trying a few different ways, I have solved it out the situation

Below is my code for the solution

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <label v-onhover>{{ msg }}</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CustomDirective",
  data() {
    return {
      str: "",
      msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App"
    };
  },
  directives: {
    onhover: {
      bind(el, binding) {
        el.onmouseover = function() {
          el.style.fontSize = "100px";
        };
        el.onmouseout = function() {
          el.style.fontSize = "15px";
        };
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped></style>
```

Here in the above example, I have used two different event mouseover and mouseout event and based on the event state, we can change the property of an element

Comment: If it wasn't the [wrong reference to the `style` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Setting_styles) of an element, you should at least fix your original question (from `el.fontSize` to `el.style.fontSize`) so people won't go around thinking you missed that part and start offering solutions that might not have been your issue in the first place. Not to mention the fact that my post is 4 minutes earlier than yours.

Comment: @jom in my question, I was confused about the same, but I resolved the issue with the correct reference so that I think my confusion may lead other to overcome using my own solution, Does it make sense ??